# What config properties does DefaultAzureCredential() needs to authenticate deployed app to a keyvault?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

Normally I would need to provide `ClientId` and `ClientSecret` in order to authenticate to key vault, but now the preferred way to authenticate to keyvault is `DefaultAzureCredential()` however it doesn't say what properties I need in my config in order to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that I'd say that `DefaultAzureCredential` is preferred, rather it is positioned as the "easiest for most."  The default credential is a chained credential that will inspect the ambient host environment and attempt to choose an identity.   The goal is to allow the same code that runs locally to run across environments, including production, without changes.  The credential priorities and hints for configuring can be found in the [README](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity#defaultazurecredential) for the library.

If you'd prefer to take control and always your client secret, the `Azure.Identity` library also offers a [ClientSecretCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential?view=azure-dotnet) that allows you to do so with the client identifier, client secret, and identifier of the Azure tenant.

All of the credential types in `Azure.Identity` derive from a common base, `TokenCredential`, and they can be used interchangeably with any of the Azure client libraries from the current generation.